too much space for the last column
I am using latex to prepare an article and I am creating a long table. The problem is that there is too much space between the last column and the one before it. Here is my code and the picture of the table:
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical 

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{booktabs}%


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[c]{c cc}
\caption{Graph embedding techniques: types, used models and algorithms \cite{cai2018comprehensive}.\label{long}}
\\
\hline
Graph Embedding Technique & Model Type & Algorithm\\ [0.5ex] 
\hline  
\multirow{11}{*}{Matrix factorization} & \multirow{6}{*}{Graph Laplacian Eigenmaps} & Isomap\\
~&~& ARE \cite{lin2005semantic}\\
~&~& LPP \cite{he2003locality}\\
~&~& SLE \cite{gong2014signed}\\
~&~& HSL \cite{sun2008hypergraph}\\
~&~& Diffusion maps\\\cmidrule{2-3}
&~\multirow{7}{*}{Node proximity matrix factorization}&LLE \cite{roweis2000nonlinear}\\
&~&~CMF \cite{}\\
&~&~GraRep \cite{cao2015grarep}\\
&~&~ULGE \cite{nie2017unsupervised}\\
&~&~FONPE \cite{pang2017flexible}\\
&~&~SPE \cite{shaw2009structure}\\
.
.
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}

enter image description here
I appreciate your ideas and comments in advance,

Please add a compilable test document and not just a code fragment.

Some cells further down in the parts of the table which you don't show us are probably wider and thus force your second column to be so wide. You can avoid this by using a fixed with column, e.g. p{3cm} instead of c (adjust the width so that the table will actually fit in your document.)

(adding all these spaces ~ is probably not the best of ideas...)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for prompt response.

I changed the code to \begin{longtable}{l  c c  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3 cm} } ...\end{longtable} and used the relevant package (arrays) but nothing changed :( 2. do you have a recommendation for what to use instead of ~?



your changing the with of the 4th column. Your table only has 3 columns. 2) nothing? Cells can be empty.


@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Do you recommend to use longtable for a spinning table? or I can use something better? Also, I changed the code to \begin{longtable}[H]{p{.40\linewidth}p{.50\linewidth}p{2\linewidth} }...\end{longtable} which helped a lot but the lines of the table continue in the right side of the page and hit the border! it seems the table never eneds from the right side...

personally I would use a longtblr from the tabularray package. This requires a bit different syntax, but makes merging cells etc. much easier.

with p{.40\linewidth}p{.50\linewidth}p{2\linewidth}  your table will have a total width of 2.9 times the width of a line. This will never fit on any page. Your columns need to sum to less than 1 times the width of a line.

\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={Graph embedding techniques: types, used models and algorithms \cite{cai2018comprehensive}},
  label={long}
]{
  colspec={@{}X[halign=l]X[halign=l]X[halign=l]@{}}
}
\toprule
Graph Embedding Technique & Model Type & Algorithm\\
\midrule
\SetCell[r=11]{} Matrix factorization & \SetCell[r=6]{} Graph Laplacian Eigenmaps & Isomap\\
&& ARE \cite{lin2005semantic}\\
&& LPP \cite{he2003locality}\\
&& SLE \cite{gong2014signed}\\
&& HSL \cite{sun2008hypergraph}\\
&& Diffusion maps\\
\cmidrule{2-3}
&\SetCell[r=6]{} Node proximity matrix factorization &LLE \cite{roweis2000nonlinear}\\
&&CMF \\
&&GraRep \cite{cao2015grarep}\\
&&ULGE \cite{nie2017unsupervised}\\
&&FONPE \cite{pang2017flexible}\\
&&SPE \cite{shaw2009structure}\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}



This was life changing!! thanks a lot!
